# cannot find package "example/str/place" Golang

Tags: golang

Почему у меня не импортируются мои модули?

Структура:

```
example/
 str/
  place/
   main.go
card.go
```

Код card.go:

```
package main 

import "example/str/place"

func main() {

    HTTPConnectionHost(os.Args[1], 80)
}
```

Код main.go:

```
package place

func HTTPConnectionHost(url string, port int) {

    type BornTemp struct {
        steel_url string 
        steel_port int32
    }

    type BEFS struct {
        steel_non_type int64
        steel_fierce_type string
    }


    http_req_check, s_err := http.Get(url)
    if s_err != nil {

        fmt.Println("0xc1EF: Fatal server error... 404")

    } else {

        fmt.Println("0xcAFFE: Direct connection established! 200")
        fmt.Println("0xcAFCC: HTTP Gzip-Reader:", http_req_check.Body, "\n")
        pw_string := strings.Replace(url, "http", "https", -1) 

        if pw_string == "http" {

            type HTTPStruct struct {
                http_url_string int64
            }
        } else if pw_string == "https" {

            type HTTPSStruct struct {
                https_url_string int64
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Или я что-то совершенно неправильно делаю? Читал документацию, вроде бы все как в офф.документации.

Comment: GOPATH настроили? Где относительно него лежит проект?

Comment: @Ainar-G да, set $GOPATH=C:\example\ и пробовал set $GOPATH=C:\example\str\place

Comment: Ну почитайте же вы уже, [как правильно настраивать окружение](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). Код должен находиться в `$GOPATH/src`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
package main 

import "./str/place"

func main() {

    place.HTTPConnectionHost(os.Args[1], 80)
}
```

Comment: Вынужден минусовать, так как относительные импорты - это уже решённый моветон в го-сообществе ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38518202/1892060), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2588lk/relative_imports_do_or_dont/)). Не говоря уже о том, что некоторые инструменты их просто не поддерживают.

Comment: @Ainar-G а без gopath не как не обойтись? я не умею просто не умею настраивать переменные среды

Comment: @Ainar-G по поводу "решенный моветон" - это вы погорячилсь. Ссылки на SO с безымянным ответом, по крайней мере, неубедительны. Я мог бы привести ссылки с совсем противоположным мнением, но не хочу холивара. Все зависит от ситуации, Go - это инструмент, и если он позволяет использовать относительные пути, значит они полезны в некоторых случаях.

Comment: @mit в чем подвох? card.go:3:8: cannot find package "./example/str/place" in:
        C:\example\example\str\place

Comment: @JackSmith Чем быстрее научитесь - тем лучше. Обсуждаются варианты поддержки "из коробки" проектов без GOPATH, но пока это только обсуждения. Если вы хотите нормальной работы всех инструментов - настройте GOPATH.

Comment: @JackSmith ссори, скопировал импорт из вашего вопроса и не поправил. Исправил ответ.

Comment: @mit забыл добавить, я так пробовал тоже. imported and not used: "_/C_/example/str/place", undefined: pi (pi=main просто другое название файла)

Comment: @JackSmith это уже другая ошибка, т.е. импорт работает, но не используется. Метод вы вызываете так `place.HTTPConnectionHost(os.Args[1], 80)` с префиксом пакета?

Comment: @mit ойййй, точно) я префикс самого файла поставил) а не пакета) теперь все заработало)

Answer (score 1):

Исходники должны лежать в GOPATH\src

Если у вас GOPATH=C:\example\

То исходники должны лежать в C:\example\src, т.е.

```
example/
 src/
   str/
    place/
      main.go
```